# Retrieving a MongoDB collection as a BSON in Node JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, mongodb, bson

I need to retrieve a MongoDB collection as a BSON document which I'll send to a remote server in my Node JS web app.

```
import { config } from 'dotenv';
import { MongoClient } from 'mongodb';
import {BSON, EJSON} from 'bson';

config();

export async function gatherBSONs() {
    let mongoClient;
 
    try {
        mongoClient = await connectToCluster(connectionString);

        const db = mongoClient.db('Schools');
        const coll = mongoClient.collection('Colorado');
        
        const collQueryResults = await coll.find().toArray();
    
        const collQueryResults_json = JSON.stringify(collQueryResults);
        const collQueryResults_json_parsed = JSON.parse(collQueryResults _json);
        const collQueryResults_json_obj = {data: collQueryResults _json_parsed};
        const collQueryResults_bson = BSON.serialize(collQueryResults_json_obj)

        console.log(EJSON.stringify(collQueryResults_bson);
    } finally {
        await mongoClient.close();
    }
 }
```

The reason for the above approach is because BSON.serialize() accepts only a JavaScript object. The main problem now is that I lose the ObjectID fields and other nested arrays in the BSON. Here's an example of 1 record:

```
{
  data: [
    {
      _id: '32492890fr22',
      subjects_taught: [Array],
      location: 'John Doe Town'
    },
    ...
}
```

I need to be able to see the nested array under "students" and _id as an ObjectID type, like below:

```
 "_id": {
      "$oid": "32492890fr22"
    },
    "subjects_taught": [
      "math",
      "history",
      "science"
    ],
    location: 'John Doe Town'
  },
...
```

Is there a more straightforward, less tedious way to get a MongoDB query result as a BSON that also maintains its original structure?

Comment: I'm a node.js/javascript Noob, but I'm wondering if you use [`raw: true` option](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/5.2/interfaces/CollectionOptions.html#raw "link to docs -->"), the serialized bytes might be useful for your application.